# French Dictionary API

Tags: api, rest, dictionary

I would have liked to be able to use an api dictionary with French words, to which I could make a get all query. Not having found anything free of rights, I turned to the wiktionary but I couldn't find how to query  all the words of the French language.
Does anyone have any ideas to help me?
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.phpspellcheck.com/Download

A dictionary is small enough that you should be able to host it on your own server.
Something like this should work.  (This is a PHP spellchecker, but there should be others for other languages)

Comment: thank you very much, I was not aware of the existence of these dictionaries.